# replacing letters with numbers using C++

Tags: c++, c

I need to replace my input letters with numbers.
`a = 00`, `b = 01`, `c = 02` and so on...
I think there is something wrong with char enc, program doesnt work when `ch == 'j'` or higher.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char ch = 'g'; // this should be replaced with some kind of an input function
    char alp[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
          'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char enc[26] = {'00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09',
                    '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
                    '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25'};
    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
        if(ch == alp[i]){
            printf("%c", enc[i]);
            break;
        }

    while(getchar()!='\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not C# and '00' or '01' are not single characters. Make enc an array of int and handle adding zero to left of single digits in printf.

Comment: you can have only one letter in char type

Comment: It has been a long time since I last saw `conio.h`. Where are you learning your C/C++ from?

Answer (score 2):

These are not C++ chars: '00','01',... because they actually contain two characters.
try to use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char ch = 'g'; // this should be replaced with some kind of an input function
char alp[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
string enc[26] = {"00","01","02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"};
for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
    if(ch == alp[i]){
        cout<<enc[i];
    }
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would downvote this answer, some people really shouldn't have some freedom until they are mature enough.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard

> A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal containing
>   a single c-char not representable in the execution character set, is
>   conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an
>   implementation-defined value.

So it would be better if instead of the second chatracter array you would define an array of pointers to string literals. Take into account that there is no any sense to define an array of objects of type std::string.

Also it is not clear why you are speaking about C++ when the program looks like it is written in C.

The code in C++ could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    size_t N = 26;
    char ch = 'g'; // this should be replaced with some kind of an input function
    const char alp[N] =
    {
       'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
       'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
    };
    const char *enc[N] = 
    {
        "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", 
        "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"
    };

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < N &&  ch != alp[i] ) i++;

    if ( i != N ) std::cout << enc[i] << std::endl;

    std::system( "PAUSE" );

    return 0;
}
```

The same code written in C could look as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 26

int main( void )
{
    char ch = 'g'; // this should be replaced with some kind of an input function
    const char alp[N] =
    {
       'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
       'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
    };
    const char *enc[N] = 
    {
        "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", 
        "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"
    };

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < N &&  ch != alp[i] ) i++;

    if ( i != N ) printf( "%s\n", enc[i] );

    system( "PAUSE" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is good, thanks. Is there any way i can do this with input? Some kind of scan perhaps?

Comment: @user3446665 In C++ you can use std::cin >> ch; In C you can use scanf( "%c", &ch );.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use an std::map for your requirement. A map stores key,value pairs. In your case the key would be the individual characters and the value would be the string that needs to be replaced. Here is an illustration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
char ch = 'b'; // this should be replaced with some kind of an input function
char alp[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
string enc[26] = {"00","01","02" /*and the rest*/};

// declare a map
map<char, string> valueDecoderMap;

// store the values in key,value form
for ( int i = 0; i < (sizeof(alp)); i++ )
{
   valueDecoderMap [ alp [ i ] ] = enc [ i ];
}

// Now search for particular value
map<char, string>::iterator mapIterator;
mapIterator = valueDecoderMap.find ( ch );
if ( mapIterator != valueDecoderMap.end () )
{
   cout << "Key = " << mapIterator->first << " Value = " << mapIterator->second << endl;
}
else
{
   cout << "No encoding present for " << ch << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

This is a more c++ oriented approach. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to completely rewrite your code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
int main(){
    char input=std::cin.get()-'a';                                //1
    if(input<9)
        std::cout<<0;
    std::cout<<int(input)<<"\n\nPress Enter to exit program. ";   //2
    std::cin.sync();                                              //3
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');//4
}
```

Explanation:

1. - `std::cin.get()` returns first character extracted from *`stdin`*.
   - `char` is a number. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) you can check which value it has for every character.
   - as you can see, letters are arranged one after another, in alphabetical order. So, when you write `'a'-'a'` you get `'\0'` (character with code `0`) for `'b'-'a'` you get `'\1'` etc.
2. You want `std::cout` to print out character's code, not character. To do this, you have to cast character to any integer type.
3. Flushes *`stdin`*.
4. Discards characters from *`stdin`*, until meets <kbd>Enter</kbd>.