# Simple encryption program in C

Tags: c

i have to make a program that changes letters and numbers into numbers. For example a=00, b=01, c=03...z=26, 0=00, 1=01...9=09. This is my code so far, but it only changes the first symbol of my input, like if i input a5235gd it would output 00. Anyone have any ideas whats wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 36

int main( void )
{
    char ch;
    scanf( "%c", &ch );
    const char alp[N] =
    {
       '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b',
       'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 
       'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
    };
    const char *enc[N] = 
    {
        "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "00", "01", 
        "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
        "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"
    };

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < N &&  ch != alp[i] ) i++;

    if ( i != N ) printf( "%s\n", enc[i] );

    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this can not be decoded.

Comment: The `scanf` statement you wrote is designed to only read one character.

Comment: Also note you are mixing characters `alp[N]` and strings `*enc[N]`. This may be what you want, but I suspect it will make things more difficult than required later on.

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Also, please explain how, in your mind, you go from `a5235gd` to `00`?

Comment: cause it only takes the first symbol which is a = 00

Comment: It is not really "your code so far", you copied it from [Vlad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25595488/2564301), without understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is it is setup to only reading a single character of input, and store that value into a variable with storage space for only a single character. I suggest you look at the manual pages for `scanf`, paying particular attention to the `%s` conversion specification, as well as read up on C strings and/or character arrays.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Answer (score -2):

Your program has so many errors it was best to start from scratch. Here is the program: ask if you have any questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char str[1000], encrypted[1000], buf[3];
    int num, i = 0;
    scanf("%s", str);              //the user inputs the string or fgets(str, 999, stdin);
    while(str[i]){
        if(isalpha(str[i])){         //check if it is a letter
            num = str[i] - 97;       //using simple ascii table you can see the value of 'a' is 97
            sprintf(buf, "%02d", num); //put the encrypted value in the buffer
            strcat(encrypted, buf);   //concatenate buffer to encrypted
        }
        else if(isdigit(str[i])){      //check if it is a digit
            num = str[i] - '0';        //this gives the value of the number as an integer
            sprintf(buf, "%02d", num); 
            strcat(encrypted, buf);   
        }
        i++;                     //point to the next letter
    }
    printf("%s\n", encrypted);     //print the encrypted message
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: str, encrypted and buf gives an error. this method is good but i have to use arrays

Comment: What is the size of strings?

Comment: `scanf("%s", str);` makes your program directly vulnerable to a buffer overflow.

Comment: 10000 symbols would be enough

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Thanks for the suggestion. In a hurry for simple programs I tend to avoid fgets to stdin and error checking but you are right.